# Newton Interpolation formula- 3rd Degree with 5 points given- Intuition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to intuitively grasp the geometric meaning of introducing the third order term delta (Yo^3) to the graph of finite difference initially set only to second order. Till second order, I can imagine that Newton formula has given addition of initial height, slope into distance and (constant curvature X distance) X distance; bracketed term being interpreted as difference in slope.
But now with third order introduction it should give additional height Delta (Yo^3) X D X D X D. It is this term that is eluding me to have clear geometric interpretation although vaguely I can feel it. It can feel that the last multiplication (seeing it in reverse order) in this term will bring about slope difference * d = change in height, but what are the previous two multiplications precisely doing geometrically? I cannot figure out with precision.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).